# Problems updating from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, 18.04

Yesterday I started Ubuntu after several weeks and got a message that a software update was available. After downloading the update it said I need to restart my computer so I did, but I got this [message](https://streamable.com/9bpzf) which I cannot understand.

Here are some [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmyYp.jpg) of the lines showing at the end of the video. Sorry but the lines are moving too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The "PCIe bus" is one of several types of hardware that connect various peripheral components, typically video cards and such, within the case of your computer.

A "PCIe bus error" is a hardware fault. The fault might be caused by a bad driver, a loose connection, a power surge, and much more. Some predicatable types of hardware fault can be overcome by a well-written driver, while loose or truly broken components cannot.

Try booting into an older kernel at the GRUB prompt. If the hardware works, then you have a driver problem (that's a bug report). If the hardware still fails, then there is nothing more Ubuntu can do.

Comment: thanks! That worked, but the message keeps appearing if it's a driver problem as you said is there anything I can do?

Comment: You can file a bug report, if it has not already bee reported. Look up how to search Ubuntu bug reports.